# Getting form collection value in a common place

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a service that I initialize on controller's contructor.

I want to pass `UserName`(this is my model's property) to this service while instantiating the service on contructor.

First question is, is it possible to get model on controller contructor? I tried but couldn't find any way to do this.

If not then the other way I thought of is to have a common function that will be called everytime any view action is executed, where I can access `FormCollection` and assign it to the service.

For this I tried overriding few controller's method like `Initialize`, `OnExecuting` etc. But I couldn't find form collection in them.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Edit**

Some more description

```
private IService _service;
public HomeController()
{
   _service = new ServiceImplementation(/*I want to pass UserName here*/);
}

public ActionResult Submit(MyModel model)
{
    _service.UserName = model.UserName; 
     /* This UserName assignment part I want to centralize, 
     somewhere in the constructor or in any common event, 
     so that this will be initialized before any action method is called */
   ...
   ...
}

public ActionResult Delete(MyModel model)
{
    _service.UserName = model.UserName; 
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "Get model on controller constructor"? Generally your model is initialized in two ways: 1) By calling some repository 2) Returning from post action as action parameter. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets - Added description